# IllegalStateException while using fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

Created a function to remove any fragments present before setting a new fragment to the container. The code is as below :

```
private static void removeAllFragments(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    while (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

The above code is called inside a function where the fragment is setup. The code is as below :

```
public void setupFragment(){
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    removeAllFragments(Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentManager));
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFragment: getBackStackEntryCount = " + 
    Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentManager).getBackStackEntryCount());
    fragmentTransaction = Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentManager).beginTransaction();
    ApprovalFragment approvalFragment = new ApprovalFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rel2, approvalFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("approval");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

After opening many other apps and once this app is evicted from memory, a crash occurs when the app is opened. The error is as below :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2178)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2238)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:836)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:796)
    at com.example.fragment.HomeFragment.removeAllFragments(HomeFragment.java:650)
    at com.example.fragment.HomeFragment.setupFragment(HomeFragment.java:565)
    at com.example.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:420)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3251)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3205)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `.getFragmentChildManager()` instead of `.getFragmentManager()` with a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`; else you'll get such `IllegalStateException` thrown.

it is unclear, how/where `HomeFragment.removeAllFragments()` is being called... and I wonder why you not just inflate, which would replace the previous fragment, unless calling `.addToBackStack()`. that log is missing the output of `Log.d`, which makes it difficult to understand what the problem is.

using `.popBackStack()` instead of `.popBackStackImmediate()` might also work there.

based upon the situation, which you describe... my best guess would be to check for `savedInstanceState == null` and only run that code which causes the crash then.

Comment: After i set `.getFragmentChildManager()`, when i call for `FragmentManager fm0 = getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment currentFragment0 = fm0.findFragmentById(R.id.rel2);`  at backPress `currentFragment0` is returning null.


Also I removed `.removeAllFragments()` method and added all fragment to the container using `fragmentTransaction.replace()` rather than `fragmentTransaction.add()` method

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue occurs because after poping the fragment from backstack you are immediately adding a new fragment into backstack.

Try to not add the new fragment into backstack.